# Are known ("old") elements being made synthetically using fusion?

Tags: fusion, elements

Are known ("old") elements being made synthetically using fusion? I hear about research about making new heavy elements, but type "making known elements" on Google and nothing comes up. Are any known elements being made in the lab to better understand magic numbers and fusional processes?

Comment: I suppose by "old", I mean Uranium and below.

Comment: There remain nuclear physics programs with accelerators which, in their heyday of the 50's-70's had the job of mapping out nuclear levels and nuclear reactions. So, one obvious question is, do they still do some of that for, e.g., undergraduate physics labs? And how do you feel about standard nuclear reactions for composition analysis, e.g. N15(p,$\alpha$)C12? or D-D neutron generators that make T as a byproduct?

Comment: @Jon Custer. Good question. I suppose I want to know more about synthetic isotopes. Can we create a more stable isotope of Astatine, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked in comments specifically about Astatine, I found the following paper:
S. Lahiri and M. Maiti, 'Recent developments in nuclear data measurements and chemical separation methods in accelerator production of astatine and technetium radionuclides', Radiochimica Acta 100(2) 85-94 (2012). To quote the abstract:

> The cyclotron produced neutron deficient technetium radionuclides (Tc-93, Tc94(m+g), Tc-95, Tc-96) have gained renewed interest in various fields, including nuclear imaging, provided they can be obtained in a pure form. Similarly, At-211 due to its moderate half-life and high intensity a-particle energy (both from At-211 as well as its transient decay product Po-211) is of prime interest in targeted therapy. Another interest is to study the astatine chemistry, which is least studied compared to other halogens due to its non-occurrence in natural systems. For maximum production of these radionuclides various parameters need to be standardized. A chemical separation is required to achieve high radiochemical purity before in-vivo application. This review describes various production routes of neutron deficient astatine and technetium radionuclides that have been reported after the year 2000. The analytical chemistry developed for separation of no-carrier-added (nca) Tc and At radionuclides in the same period is also discussed in detail.

So, I would say that yes, folks are still making and looking at nuclei, and there is an entire journal devoted to it...

Answer (score 0):

Being slightly mischievous and pedantic, many elements that most people think of as synthetic actually arise in nature in minute quantities: plutonium and neptunium in pitchblende uranium ore, for example. Such elements arise in nature pretty much as we would make them synthetically. For example, spontaneous fission of uranium is one (minor) process whereby natural uranium $^{238} {\rm U}$ decays. This emits neutrons, which can be captured by neighboring $^{238} {\rm U}$ nucleusses. When the later happens, the resulting unstable $^{239}{\rm U}$ nucleus underdoes, with a halflife of 25 minutes, spontaneous beta decay to $^{239}{\rm Np}$, which, then undergoes another beta decay (halflife 2 days) to $^{239}{\rm Pu}$. This last element is very stable with a half life of 25 000 years. See this [Scientific American article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/do-transuranic-elements-s/)

Likewise Francium $^{223}{\rm Fr}$ occurs in nature through similar processes in uranium and thorium ores. Owing to its halflife of 22 minutes it's estimated that only about 20 grams of it lie in the Earth's crust at any one time.